# How to install Manjaro ARM in a VM on Raspberry Pi 4 running Fedora 36 server?

Tags: raspberry-pi, virtual-machine, manjaro

I have a raspberry pi 4 with 8GB running Fedora 36 Server. On it, I have a few VMs guests successfully running under kvm, specifically `alpine` and `debian` Linux. However, I can't seem to get Manjaro to install in a VM:

I used the following commands to create and start a Manjaro VM. Same works for Alpine and debian11, both start the installation wizard once the VM runs. However, this doesn't work with Manjaro - the VM is created and the console connects, but with Manjaro the installation doesn't start, instead I get following error:

`Image type X64 can't be loaded on AARCH64 UEFI system.`

I downloaded ARM two distinct images, both result in the same error: `Manjaro-ARM-minimal-generic-22.08.img.xz` and `Manjaro-ARM-minimal-rpi4-22.08.img`.

Is there a different setting / configuration to get this to work, or will it never work in a UEFI environment as the error suggests ?

I used the following commands to create the VM:

1. Create a qcow2 disk: `qemu-img create -f qcow2 /data1/kvm/mj1.qcow2 5G`
2. Create the VM: `virt-install -n mj1 --memory 1024 --arch aarch64 --vcpus 2 --disk /data1/kvm/mj1.qcow2,device=disk,bus=virtio --osinfo detect=on,name=manjaro --boot uefi  --noreboot --network bridge=virbr0 --cdrom /data1/kvm/images/Manjaro-ARM-minimal-generic-22.08.img.xz`

```
Starting install...
Creating domain...                                                                                                                              |    0 B  00:00:00     
Running text console command: virsh --connect qemu:///system console mj1
Connected to domain 'mj1'
Escape character is ^] (Ctrl + ])
Tpm2GetCapabilityPcrs - 00000004
alg - 4
alg - B
alg - C
alg - D
Image type X64 can't be loaded on AARCH64 UEFI system.




BdsDxe: failed to load Boot0001 "UEFI QEMU QEMU CD-ROM " from PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0x2)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Scsi(0x0,0x0): Not Found
BdsDxe: failed to load Boot0003 "UEFI Misc Device 2" from PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0): Not Found
BdsDxe: failed to load Boot0002 "UEFI Misc Device" from VenHw(93E34C7E-B50E-11DF-9223-2443DFD72085,00): Not Found
BdsDxe: loading Boot0004 "EFI Internal Shell" from Fv(64074AFE-340A-4BE6-94BA-91B5B4D0F71E)/FvFile(7C04A583-9E3E-4F1C-AD65-E05268D0B4D1)
BdsDxe: starting Boot0004 "EFI Internal Shell" from Fv(64074AFE-340A-4BE6-94BA-91B5B4D0F71E)/FvFile(7C04A583-9E3E-4F1C-AD65-E05268D0B4D1)


UEFI Interactive Shell v2.2
EDK II
UEFI v2.70 (EDK II, 0x00010000)
Mapping table
     BLK2: Alias(s):
          VenHw(93E34C7E-B50E-11DF-9223-2443DFD72085,00)
     BLK0: Alias(s):
          PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0x2)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Scsi(0x0,0x0)
     BLK1: Alias(s):
          PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)
Press ESC in 1 seconds to skip startup.nsh or any other key to continue.
Shell>
```

Comment: Hey man. Just checking in. Did you ever have any luck with resolving this issue? I'm having a similar issue.